# Methods of Audio Manager class not working properly with lower version

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Here is my code to change the Ringer Mode of the Android Device :

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int max = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, max, 0);
```

Code works absolutely **fine** with Android Jelly Bean but **doesn't** works with Ginger Bread !
I thought that methods might have been added in API after Ginger Bread but it was added in API level 1 as in developers site :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamMaxVolume(int)

So, can anyone please help and tell me what is going wrong here and possible solution.
A **BIG** thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

check the following code

```
public void setRinger2Normal(){       
    AudioManager audioManager= 
     (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL); 
}
```

Comment: I want to set the Volume to its maximum value how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may helps you

```
AudioManager am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

//For Normal mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

//For Silent mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

//For Vibrate mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

**This is working with me**

```
public void setMaxVolume(Context mContext) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    }
```

Comment: I want to set the Volume to the maximum level..is there any way to do that

Comment: with which device you are using

Comment: currently i ran on emulator API 17...but it didn't work

Comment: its working when i use STREAM_RING(on emulator) instead of STREAM_MUSIC but THIS doesn't work with Ginger Bread Device

Comment: please try on real device rather emulator